# redis - logstash - influxdb datatransfer

Tags: redis, logstash, influxdb

i've got a redis db, logstash and both elasticsearch an influxdb.
i'm transferring keys from redis to elasticsearch, which works fine and want to test influxdb which does not work at all.

has anybody a valid connector for influxdb or how should i provide the data in redis to make this thing work?

this is my influx-db connection which only raises errors

```html
  influxdb {
        host => "localhost"
        measurement => "sensor1"
        allow_time_override => true
        use_event_fields_for_data_points => true
        exclude_fields => ["@version", "@timestamp", "sequence", "type", "host"]

    }
```

this is my redis connection which works fine

```html
redis
{
  host => "localhost"
  data_type => "list"
  key => "vortex"
  threads => 4
  type => "testrecord"
  codec => "plain"
}
```

i tried this line format

"sensor1,measure=1 1489594615.9747"
as list for redis e.g

```html
key: vortex

values:
sensor1,measure=1 1489594615.9747
sensor1,measure=1 1489594615.9747
sensor1,measure=1 1489594615.9747
sensor1,measure=1 1489594615.9747
sensor1,measure=1 1489594615.9747
....
```

but this also doesn't work.

has anybody a clou how to get data from redis via logstash into influxdb?

Answer (score 1):

after searching around for hours i solved it the following way:

- first step into the installed version of influxdb plugin inside logstash folder e.g. C:\tools\logstash-5.2.2\vendor\bundle\jruby\1.9\gems\logstash-output-influxdb-4.0.0\lib\logstash\outputs
- search for the file influxdb.rb (should be the only file inside the folder)
- replace the retention policy

  The retention policy to use
- **config :retention_policy, :validate => :string, :default => "autogen"**
- //config :retention_policy, :validate => :string, :default => "default" << orignial

  - in redis i used the following string format (without timestamp)
    foo=70617 bar=3
  - the configfile for logsash is shown below - just as a sample of how to do it so it finally works :-)

```html
input {

   
  redis{
  host => "localhost"
  data_type => "list"
  key => "vortex"
  threads => 4
  type => "testrecord"
  codec => "plain"

 }
 }

filter {
           kv {
              add_field => {
                "test1" => "yellow=cat"
                "test=space" => "making= life=hard"
                "feild= space" => "pink= dog"
              }
           }
}

output {

 stdout { codec => rubydebug }

           influxdb {
             host => "localhost"
             measurement => "myseries"
             allow_time_override => true
             use_event_fields_for_data_points => true
             exclude_fields => ["@version", "@timestamp", "sequence", "message", "type", "host"]
             send_as_tags => ["bar", "baz", "test1", "test=space"]
  }
      }
```